# T-SQL - check gap in datetime data for every minute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

We have a database that records data from a system every minute

```
+---------+-------------------------+  
| Id      | EntryDate               |     
+---------+-------------------------+   
| 8093562 | 2019-05-17 15:01:25.000 |  
| 8093563 | 2019-05-17 15:02:25.000 |  
| 8093564 | 2019-05-17 15:03:25.000 |  
| 8093565 | 2019-05-17 15:04:25.000 |  
| 8093566 | 2019-05-17 15:05:25.000 |  
| 8093568 | 2019-05-17 15:07:25.000 |  
| 8093569 | 2019-05-17 15:08:25.000 |  
| 8093780 | 2019-05-17 15:09:25.000 |  
| 8093781 | 2019-05-17 15:10:25.000 |  
+---------+-------------------------+
```

I am trying to make a query that can find if there is any gap between the minutes. For example in the above data, data at 15:06 is missing.

Can't figure out how to do this in SQL query.

Comment: So what will be your expected output? `2019-05-17 15:06:25.000` or the `Id` ?

Comment: 2019-05-17 15:06:25.000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `LEAD()` with `CASE`, you can get your expected result:

```
SELECT ResultDate FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LEAD(EntryDate, 1) OVER(ORDER BY EntryDate),EntryDate) < -1) THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, +1, EntryDate) END AS ResultDate
    FROM TableName
) Q WHERE ResultDate IS NOT NULL
```

Demo with given sample data:

```
DECLARE  @TestTable TABLE (Id INT, EntryDate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Id, EntryDate) VALUES  
(8093562, '2019-05-17 15:01:25.000'),
(8093563, '2019-05-17 15:02:25.000'),
(8093564, '2019-05-17 15:03:25.000'),
(8093565, '2019-05-17 15:04:25.000'),
(8093566, '2019-05-17 15:05:25.000'),
(8093568, '2019-05-17 15:07:25.000'),
(8093569, '2019-05-17 15:08:25.000'),
(8093780, '2019-05-17 15:09:25.000'),
(8093781, '2019-05-17 15:10:25.000');

SELECT ResultDate FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LEAD(EntryDate, 1) OVER(ORDER BY EntryDate),EntryDate) < -1) THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, +1, EntryDate) END AS ResultDate
    FROM @TestTable
) Q WHERE ResultDate IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
ResultDate
-----------------------
2019-05-17 15:06:25.000
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3aed2518f23cfca79f7b2fe85c60d5c)

Comment: Thanks the query works perfect for the above data
However if the DB has multiple minutes missing, it returns only the first minute

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b8103d91b3234eb002abf611bbcc05fd

Comment: @AnsarMuhammad . . . This answers the question that you asked.  I would suggest that you accept this answer and ask a new question that is clearer with respect to multiple missing minutes.

Comment: @AnsarMuhammad Thanks for accepting the answer. If you are posting a new quetsion with multiple minute gap issue, I can post an answer for that.

Comment: @AnsarMuhammad Please find the [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=db21f2e46ae6cb55fa9ee6f33cef2a47) for DB has multiple minutes missing issue.